# In what normal form is the given table?

Tags: database, database-normalization

Consider the following relational schema for a library database:

```
Book (Title,Author,Catalog_no, Publisher, Year, Price)
```

with the following functional dependencies:

```
I. Title, Author -> Catalog_no
II. Catalog_no -> Title, Author, Publisher, Year
III. Publisher, Title, Year -> Price
```

Assume `{Author, Title}` is the key for the schema. In what normal form is the given schema?

I think that the table is only in 1NF and not in 2NF. As per the `III FD`,  the attribute `Price` depends partially on the key because of the dependency on `Title` and not on `Author`.

Please let me know your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Catalogue number is a key; it determines directly everything except price, and transitively via FD 3 it determines price too.  Therefore, Title + Author is also a key as it determines catalogue number.

On the face of it, if two different authors each write a book called "How to write books" that is published by the same publisher ("Duplicative Publishing") in the same year, then the books must cost the same, even if one is a 50 page souped up pamphlet and the other is a 500 page tome.  It's a ridiculous FD in the real world.  However, the question isn't about the real world.

Given the definition of [Second Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form), there is no escaping the fact that the price is not determined by a whole key, so the relation is not in 2NF.